# How should I approach combining react-i18next with content which is fetched from database?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next

I have a React application and I want to make it a multi-language webpage (English and Bulgarian). So far I've got the hang of translating the static content, such as header, footer, navigation buttons, homepage components, etc. But let's say that I have a list of posts in both languages that gets fetched from my database and I would like to display them according to the language that the user has selected. What would be the most reasonable approach in this situation? My initial guess was to check for the currently selected language and fetch the posts that correspond to that language. Is there a better way to do achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

With your use case, having a bigger amount of text, I think it is the best if you use the currently used language, i.e. [i18next.resolvedLanguage](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#resolvedlanguage) and fetches the appropriate blog post.